# How can I make self-contained async functions that doesn't stop in Python?

Tags: python, loops, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to make a self-contained async function inside a loop in Python. The idea is to have a loop that iterates over the functions, one to get information (let's call it "FunctionA") and the other to process it ("FunctionB"). The FunctionB usually takes some time to work and at that time the FunctionA doesn't get any information, so I decided to make FunctionB asynchronous.
In simplified form this is my function:

```
 async def main():
        while(True):
            data = functionA()
            if (data):
                task = asyncio.create_task(functionB(data))
            await task
asyncio.run(main())
```

The problem is the last await. If I don't use it the function main restarts the FunctionB at each turn of the loop, but if I use it the code has to wait for FunctionB and I have the same timing issue as I don't use asynchronous functions.
How could I make it? Is there another methods to get it?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the `"Producer-consumer design pattern"`, where `functionA()` is the `Producer` and `functionB()` is the `Consumer`.

[here](https://www.askpython.com/python/producer-consumer-problem) you can find a tutorial with code examples that can help you implement what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It is an interesting design, but I thimk that it doesn't exactly match what I'm looking for because the consumer has to wait and call the producer and I wish to have the producer all the time working and sending data to the consumer, without the sleep part.